# Google font does not display in Firefox

Tags: fonts

I am using an open source google font on my website, inserted via a link into the head of my html:

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'
>   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

It renders in all browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE) but not in Firefox.

Can anybody assist me with fixing this?

**EDIT [SOLVED]**

Found the solution. I was missing the link to Open Sans Light that includes the font weight in html as well as the correct font weight in the css:

**HTML**

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'
>   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>     https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300'
>   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

**CSS**

> font-family: "Open Sans";
>   font-weight: 300;

Comment: If it's Firefox 37 or 38, those require woff2 flag support set to true.

Comment: I use Firefox 41. I notice that it might be related to the font-style (light). The text that is marked as normal Open Sans displays correctly, but text that is marked as Open Sans Light does not display.

Comment: impossible to tell without source code. share a url or put the code up on a site you can edit...

Comment: Thanks for your help Albert. I was using 'Open Sans Light' in the CSS instead of the appropriate font weight 300. See update above.